# Finding the cause for a deprecated syscall

Tags: system-calls, dhcp

I am a rank newbie & out of my element here, but I need to know something:

While perusing `journalctl` output, the following line appeared repeatedly for a time, and then, after a point in time, it stopped appearing:

> ... kernel: ICMPv6: process 'dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time_ms instead

`dhcpcd` is the DHCP *client* daemon for my (Raspberry Pi OS) system. I concluded (probably incorrectly) that this deprecated `syscall` was something called out specifically in the `dhcpcd` source code. In an effort to find that code, I tried this:

```sh
$ grep -Ril 'net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time' ~/dhcpcd5 
$ # where ~/dhcpcd5 is the 'source package' fetched fm the RPi archives
```

Unfortunately, this yielded nothing - no match. How do I learn where & how `dhcpcd` came to use this now-deprecated syscall? Is this the result of my system's kernel being out-of-date - or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here, it should fix the issue:

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=269327